# Linq Query With Entities and Group By

Tags: linq, ef-code-first

I have Entities as shown below (using .NET Code First with Repository Pattern):

```
public abstract class BaseContent : Entity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssignedMedia> AssignedMedias { get; set; }
}

public partial class Library : BaseContent
{
    public Library()
    {
        this.AssignedMedias = new List<AssignedMedia>();
    }
}

public class Media : BaseContent
{
    public Media()
    {
        this.AssignedMedias = new List<AssignedMedia>();
    }
}

public class AssignedMedia : Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //BaseContent reference ID
    public Guid AssignedId { get; set; }

    public Guid MediaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Media Media { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseContent BaseContent { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'm trying get query (as Dictionary<string, List<Media>>) as group by!
For Instance:

```
var list = from bc in Libraries
    join a in AssignedMedias on bc.ID equals a.AssignedId
    join m in Medias on a.MediaId equals m.ID
    select new {
        LibraryName = bc.Name, MediaList = ??? 
    };
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how can I get ToDictionary() linq type query as shown above. LibraryName should as group by and should contain related Media as List<Media> for each Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `join` when you already have the Entity associations mapped properly. You can write the query like so:

```
var libraryAssignedMedia = Libraries.ToDictionary(
    l => l.Name, // Key selection.
    l => l.AssignedMedias.Select(am => am.Media)); // Value selection.
```

Comment: `var libraryAssignedMedia = _unitOfWork.Repository<Library>().Query()` `.Include(l => l.AssignedMedias.Select(s => s.Media)).Select().ToDictionary(` `l => l.Name, // Key selection.` `l => l.AssignedMedias.Select(am => am.Media)); // Value selection.` **little changes but your way is helpful**